# Implementations for single frequently updated Column in heavily indexed table using Spring-Data

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a Data Object that I expect to have a single very frequently updated column and a number of mostly static columns that will be searched on.

```
 asset(
    id PRIMARY_KEY,
    group_id REFERENCES group(id)
    last_contact bigint,
    name varchar,
    type varchar,
    version varchar,
    ....

)
```

The last_contact column is expected to be updated very frequently, while other columns will be updated few times

Expected Queries are

- find asset by id
- find asset by group order by last_contact
- find asset by name order by last_contact
  ...etc

I am having difficulty deciding on implementation for these goals.

The Options I can see are

1. Store last_contact in same row

   - Simplest to Implement, but worried about frequent writes on the row
2. Store last_contact in oneToOne relation base on asset id

   - Finding it difficult to implement in spring data and hibernate.
   - Unsure if it is a good implementation for this problem (eg would it be possible/efficient to sort by last_contact in this model)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the best performance solution, it is definitely storing it in the same table as a new column. Another thing to consider, if you are updating a single column create your `@Modifying @Query` in your repository that just updates this field. This will significantly improve performance comparing to `entity.save()` because you are updating a single column instead of the whole entity.